# How to set post slug when using wp_insert_post();?

Tags: pages, slug, wp-insert-post

My theme uses a custom template to render some contents. To use this template, I'm hooking into `after_switch_theme` to create my own page after the theme is activated, and then assign this template to it.

This is how I do it:

```
$new_page_title = __('Custom page');
$new_page_content = '';
$new_page_template = 'page-custom.php';
$page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
$new_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $new_page_title,
        'post_content' => $new_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_slug' => 'my-custom-slug'
);
if( !isset($page_check->ID) ){
    $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
    if(!empty($new_page_template)){
        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
    }
}
```

However, the page's slug is always following the title. It means, the slug is always `custom-page`. Seems like [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) doesn't support post slug, since there isn't any in the code reference.

I need to set the slug since the page's title is something very popular, and there might be another page with the same slug already existing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The parameter to insert a custom slug is:

```
'post_name' => 'my-custom-slug'
```

Not `post_slug` as  one would think! :)

Comment: Note that if a post with slug exists already, `wp_insert_post` will create a new post with an automatically generated `post_name`